# Проблемы с SVG Android - изображение имеет дефекты или вообще отсутствует. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-drawable

Проблема: после обработки SVG в VectorDrawable средствами Android Studio изображение имеет дефекты или вообще отсутствует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Открываем SVG изображение в **Adobe Illustrator**;
2. Выбираем "Сохранить как".
3. В параметрах SVG: `Профиль: SVG 1.0`, Шрифты: `Тип: SVG`, `Сокращение знакового состава: Все глифы`.
4. Сохраняем SVG.
5. Импортируем SVG привычным способом в Android Studio.

*Этот способ **самый эффективный**, особенно, **если есть текст**. Но если нет Adobe Illustrator, тогда **можно попробовать способы ниже**. **Но это трата времени** (сам когда-то так мучался - лень было поставить AI).*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно ещё **переобразовать текст в кривые**.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ошибка парсинга svg - нужно поменять:

```
<svg width="480.003" height="483.333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

на

```
<svg width="480" height="483" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

---

̶И̶л̶и̶ ̶э̶т̶о̶т̶ [̶с̶е̶р̶в̶и̶с̶](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/). ̶Б̶ы̶в̶а̶л̶о̶ ̶ч̶т̶о̶ ̶п̶о̶с̶л̶е̶ ̶о̶б̶р̶а̶б̶о̶т̶к̶и̶ ̶о̶с̶т̶а̶в̶а̶л̶и̶с̶ь̶ ̶п̶р̶о̶б̶л̶е̶м̶ы̶, ̶н̶о̶ ̶я̶ ̶п̶р̶о̶с̶т̶о̶ ̶п̶р̶о̶г̶о̶н̶я̶л̶ ̶S̶V̶G̶ ̶в̶ ̶в̶е̶к̶т̶о̶р̶н̶о̶м̶ ̶р̶е̶д̶а̶к̶т̶о̶р̶е̶ ̶и̶ ̶о̶п̶я̶т̶ь̶ ̶и̶с̶п̶о̶л̶ь̶з̶о̶в̶а̶л̶ [̶э̶т̶о̶](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/).

Comment: буква "z" случайно.